# How to set variable in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

I try to use variable to replace hardcode version in my `build.gradle`,
but it does not work. Below is example of my build script. My gradle is 4.10
Any hints are more than welcome!

```
ext {
   springVersion = "2.0.4.RELEASE"
}

buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springVersion}")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The ext block needs to be nested inside the buildscript section:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springVersion = "2.0.4.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springVersion}")
    }
}
```

Apparently the buildscript block gets evaluated before anything else.